# How can I resolve my compilation error and what changed should I have to make it to improve

Tags: c

Compilation error in my source code In c:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quF7q.png]

Please tell me what is this compilation error and how to resolve it and what corrections can I make

Comment: you mean printf not print

Comment: Please do not post pictures, use text instead. BTW: it's `printf()` in C, not `print()`.

Comment: Please show text, not links to pictures, or even pictures.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be "savant" instead of "sevant".

Comment: A _return_ is missing at the end

Comment: `num <= 10` is incorrect for *Enter a number less than 10*.

Comment: @bruno it is not required.

Comment: @WeatherVane what is the exit value without ? ;-)

Comment: @bruno `int main()` is the only non-void function which does not need to explicitly return a value. See C11 5.1.2.2.3 para 1: *If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument; **reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0**. If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.* (My bolding).

Comment: @WeatherVane ah ok, thank you ... but I prefer to be explicit ^^

Comment: Ya I made a mistake and resolve it tnks to all of u

Answer (score 0):

if I cumulate all the remarks and more :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num;

  printf("enter a number less than 10 : ");
  if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
    puts("invalid input");
  else if (num < 10)
    puts("what an obidient savant you are!");
  else
    puts("wrong number");

  return 0; // may be return an other value on error cases ?
}
```

Examples :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter a number less than 10 : 1
what an obidient savant you are!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter a number less than 10 : z
invalid input
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter a number less than 10 : 20
wrong number
```

Answer (score 0):

- In C, printing is done through `printf()`, however, you wrote
  `print()`. (So you forgot an 'f'.)

The correct program reads:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int num;

  printf("Enter a number less than 10:");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  if (num < 10) {
    printf("What an obedient servant you are!\n");
  }
}
```

Notice the `\n`, by the way: it prints a newline.